# How many ways to get a sum of consecutive whole numbers that total x?

Tags: math, permutation

How would one go to programmatically tackle these questions:

> How many different ways are there to write:
>
> - a) 2021 as the sum of consecutive whole numbers?
> - b) x as the sum of consecutive whole numbers?

Comment: really!    

wow I never expected there would be so many digits!  

What if the order of the numbers is important, the numbers have to be consecutive and there can be negative values?  
an example from the question:   

** 3 = 1 + 2, 3 = 0 + 1 + 2, 3 = -2 + -1 + 0 + 1 + 2 + 3.**  

I know it's kind of an unusual question!

Comment: The title doesn't match the body of the question. For `2021 = 43 * 47` the number of ways to write it as a sum of consecutive integers is `2*2 - 1 = 3`, see for example [Sum of consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100897/sum-of-consecutive-numbers) (that's not including the single term `2021 = 2021` sum).

Comment: @dxiv, can you please let me know what the title should be?

Comment: The title says "*consecutive*" and "*permutations*" while the actual question says neither, so it's hard to guess which one you meant to ask.

Comment: oh...  
I never expected that!  
sorry for the stupid title!

Comment: So, is it "*sum of* ***consecutive*** *whole numbers*" (title), or "*sum of whole numbers*" (question)?

Comment: The title is the one I was asking...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing the order of the numbers isn't important, there are `8518741657943308344041302580996941768179250799` ways to write `2021` as a sum of positive integers. It's called the [partition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). There isn't a simple formula, but there is a recurrence relation that allows to calculate a lot of values.

The function is implemented in Python's [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/combinatorics/partitions.html):

```py
from sympy import partition

print(partition(2021))
```

Now, for the new question, to write `2021` as the sum of consecutive integers: `n + n+1 + ... + m-1 + m = 2021`. First note that negative values for `n` don't add anything interesting.  When `n < -m`, the sum would clearly be negative. Otherwise, the negative values just "eat up" the corresponding positive values, and you get the same sum as a positive solution.

The sum of the numbers from `1` to `m` is `tri(m)=m*(m+1)/2`, ([the triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)). The sum of the numbers from `n` to `m` is just `tri(m)-tri(n-1)`. These equations can be solved by a [SAT/SMT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_modulo_theories) such as [Z3](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm):

```py
from z3 import Int, Solver, And, Or, sat

s = Solver()
m = Int('m')
n = Int('n')
s.add(And(n > 0, n < 2022))
s.add(n <= m)
s.add(And(m > 0, m < 2022))
s.add(m * (m + 1) - n * (n - 1) == 2021 * 2)
while s.check() == sat:
    mi = s.model()[m].as_long()
    ni = s.model()[n].as_long()
    if ni > mi - 30:
        print("+".join([str(i) for i in range(ni, mi + 1)]), end="=")
    else:
        print("+".join([str(i) for i in range(ni, ni + 6)]), "+...+",
              "+".join([str(i) for i in range(mi - 4, mi + 1)]), end="=", sep="")
    print(sum([i for i in range(ni, mi + 1)]))
    s.add(Or(m != mi, n != ni))
```

Output:

```
26+27+28+29+30+...+64+65+66+67+68=2021
20+21+22+23+24+...+62+63+64+65+66=2021
1010+1011=2021
2021=2021
```

So, for 2021 there are 4 positive solutions (and 4 corresponding solutions that would include the negative numbers from `1-n` to `m`).

Comment: Thanks @JohanC for the elegant answer! This question finally makes sense!